# Обновление файла на странице редактирования

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть небольшое задание : на странице редактирования нужно обновить файл с последующим его обновлением в бд, удалением старого если такой есть и отправление нового на сервер.Помимо файла есть еще поля ввода. Если не выбираем новый файл, оставляем прежний(исходный).

// так и не могу понять почему в sql запрос к file выбирается прошлый файл, если я выбрал новый

update.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
session_start();

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['id']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['title']);
$author = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['author']);
$place = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['place']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['year']);
$publisher = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['publisher']);
$compedit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['compedit']);
$countpages = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['countpages']);
$archive = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['archive']);
$BBK = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['BBK']);
$inventnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['inventnumber']);
$numbinstances = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['numbinstances']);
$lasttaker = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lasttaker']);

// Получаем имя старого файла
$sql = "SELECT file FROM infprintedit WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$old_file = $row['file'];

// Проверяем, был ли выбран новый файл
$old_file = $row['file'];
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (!empty($old_file) && file_exists('../uploads/' . $old_file)) {
        unlink('../uploads/' . $old_file);
    }
    $new_file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $new_file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $new_file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($new_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    if (in_array($new_file_ext, $extensions)) {
        $file_name = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $new_file_ext;
        move_uploaded_file($new_file_tmp, '../uploads/' . $file_name);
        $file = $file_name;
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file extension.";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $file = $old_file;
}
// Обновляем запись в БД
$sql = "UPDATE infprintedit SET title='$title', 
                               file='$file', 
                               author='$author', 
                               year='$year', 
                               place='$place', 
                               publisher='$publisher', 
                               compedit='$compedit', 
                               countpages='$countpages', 
                               archive='$archive', 
                               BBK='$BBK', 
                               inventnumber='$inventnumber', 
                               numbinstances='$numbinstances', 
                               lasttaker='$lasttaker' 
        WHERE id='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully!";
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($sql);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($connect);
}
?>
```

edit.php

```
                <div id="imageContainer">
                    <a href="#" onclick="openModal(this)">
                        <img id="imagePreview" src="uploads/<?= empty($file) ? $row['file'] : $file ?>" width="200" height="300" margin="auto">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="inputWrapper">
                    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="image" onchange="showImage(this)">
                </div>
```